# loading and saving mongoDB database from/to disk with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am new to mongoDB and pymongo, trying to learn how to load and save databases from/to disk so that I can carry it around, to send it to people etc. I've read the tutorial on http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html but couldn't find useful information about saving and loading a db.

Assuming we create a database like:

```
import pymongo
mongo = pymongo.Connection()
db = mongo['my_db']
col = db['my_col']
col.insert({'name': 'Adam','occupation': 'student'})
col.insert({'name': 'John','occupation': 'officer'})
#how can we save the database to disk after this point 
#and later read it from another program?
```

Comment: read this at first http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html

Comment: As a matter of fact, I did, there is no such information for saving and loading db.

Comment: I don't understand what you asking. `insert` saves data to the database. If you are load "from/to disk" where do you expect it to load to? I think you may need to understand the fundamentals of databases here.

Comment: I mean when we want to use the database from another program, not necessarily from the same computer. Similar to sqlite's *.db files.

Comment: MongoDB comes with inbuilt server that transmits from your computer, if you wish to make the files portable (MongoDB is not an embedded database unlike SQLite) then you can copy your MongoDB directory normally located in `/data/db/mongodb`

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting, can I then load the db in other computers?

Comment: Yes, by replacing that other computers folder with the one you copied. There are of course other ways, i.e. you could take a hot backup using MongoDBs backup tools of specific subsets of data and then use importing tools to restore that data on other machines.

Comment: Alright, I guess I know now what I am looking for, importing/exporting data subsets in mongoDB, @Sammaye could you post that as an answer?

Comment: Will do, I'll get more info and that together for you to sift through.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MongoDB files are portable and there are a couple of ways to achieve what you are looking for:

- Copy the data directory for `mongod` to another computer. This directory is normally based in `/data/db/mongodb`. On the other computer you would simply replace the remote directory with the one you copied and restart the remote `mongod` at which point you will have the data on their system. As far as I know MongoDB has no hot swap feature here whereby you can switch, on-demand, the directories without downtime.
- Make hot backups of your data and use MongoDBs export and import functions to select subsets of data to place onto the remote machine. You would do hot backup via `mongodump` and `mongorestore`. You can find the general doc page on that here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/backups/#using-binary-database-dumps-for-backups
- Make CSV/JSON exports of your data and import it onto the remote computer. This is a lot like the binary backups in this particular scenario except they are also more readable to end parties etc. I should also note that this method only inserts, it is the same as a batch insert client side iterating (in something like PHP) a CSV and calling a batch insert on the MongoDB server. You can find more information about `mongoexport` and `mongoimport` (the programs that do this) here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/import-export/

You can also find nice general information that relates to backing up data and moving it and restoring it on foreign machines here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/backups/

Answer (score 2):

- To insert a new entry in mongodb using pymongo what you did is sufficient. i.e. doing this

  col.insert({'name': 'John','occupation': 'officer'})

will save these entries automatically in the collection. You can also change the entries using pymongo like this:

```
col.update({'name': 'Adam'},{'$set':{'occupation': 'officer'}})
```

Also its a good practise to close connection at the end:

```
mongo.close()
```